# Find average in python

Tags: python

can anyone help?

```
import math
a = int(raw_input('Enter Average:')) # Average number probability
c = int(raw_input('Enter first number:')) #
d = int(raw_input('Enter last number:')) #
e = 2.71828
for b in range(c,d+1):
    x = (a**b)/math.factorial(b)*(e**-a)
    odd = round (1/x*0.92, 2)
    print odd
```

How to find average value of odd?

Comment: It would be nice if you could explain what your program was trying to do, what problem you're facing, and how we could help. Often doing that helps you solve your own query. Also, as much as we'd like, we can't read minds.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What exactly is your goal? Average of what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do two things:

- Accumulate all of those `odd` values into, e.g., a `list`, then average the result.
- Keep a running total and count and divide.

(I'm assuming that by "average" you mean "arithmetic mean". If you mean something different, the details are different, but the basic idea is the same.)

For the first:

```
odds = []
for b in range(c,d+1):
    x = (a**b)/math.factorial(b)*(e**-a)
    odd = round (1/x*0.92, 2)
    print odd
    odds.append(odd)
print sum(odds) / len(odds)
```

If you don't what [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) or [`len`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) do, read the docs.

For the second:

```
total, count = 0, 0
for b in range(c,d+1):
    x = (a**b)/math.factorial(b)*(e**-a)
    odd = round (1/x*0.92, 2)
    print odd
    total += odd
    count += 1
print total / count
```

Comment: that's it, I forgot append to use, thank you so much :)

Comment: And for the completely unreadable one-(and a half)-liner: `a=int(raw_input("probability: ")); result=sum([round(1/((a**b)/math.factorial(b)*(2.71828**(-a)))*0.92, 2) for count,b in enumerate(range(int(raw_input("start: ")), int(raw_input("end: "))+1),1)])/count`

Comment: (assuming you're in python2, of course, since iirc py3 wouldn't leak the `count` variable outside of the list comp)

Comment: @AdamSmith: You're right, 3.x, won't leak the `count`… but you don't need it thanks to `statistics`. Which means you don't need `enumerate` either. Plus `input` is shorter than `raw_input`, so I can waste even more of my comment writing text and still fit the 3.4 code with plenty of room to spare: `a=int(input('probability:')); result=statistics.mean(round(1/((a**b)/math.factorial(b)*(2.71828**-a))*0.92, 2) for b in range(int(input('start:')),int(input('end:'))+1))`. That's 169 characters vs. 202, proving that 3.x is 19.5% better than 2.x. :)

Comment: @abarnert can't argue with statistics (or `statistics`!)

Comment: @AdamSmith: Notice that I cheated by also removing a couple of unnecessary spaces from your version. Lies, damn lies, and `statistics.__package__` and all that.